# A Strange Computer : Cache based computer

Tags: computers, cpu, computer-architecture, cache

In the Operating System class I heard from Professor that in some institute, researchers are working on cache based computer ( means the computer that don't have RAM and have a big cache ( probably 1 or 2 GB ) ). Now I want to know, is there anyone who knows some infornation about these computers ?if someone knows, please help me. thanks

Comment: The question does not contain enough detail AND the description is probably incorrect. "Cache" **IS** (in most cases you will meet) RAM which is controlled by the system rather than by the program directly. For a computing system to do useful work it must be able to access and alter variable storage which is what RAM is. Unless you redefine what RAM" means conceptually then you cannot have a useful RAM-less computer.

Comment: I think that the difference is that the cache is on-chip, so the access is much quicker

Comment: The difference is that cache is usually RAM, but RAM may or may not be cache and usually isn't.

Comment: there are two things that you could be referring to: 1) using RAM to store persistent data (this could only work in situations where there is a reliable Uninterruptible Power Supply), or 2) using SRAM for main memory.

Comment: I wonder if the person was referring to a Cache-Only Memory Architecture.  Wikipedia has a short article and knowing that name could facilitate a search for academic papers.

Answer (score 3):

The question does not contain enough detail AND the description is probably incorrect.

"Cache" **IS** (in most cases you will meet) RAM which is controlled by the system rather than by the program directly.

RAM is an acronym for "Random Access Memory" which means a "bank" of storage registers which the program can write to and read from as required under program control. For a computing system to do useful work it must be able to access and alter variable storage, which is what RAM is.

Unless you redefine what "RAM" means conceptually then you cannot have a useful RAM-less computer.

Comment: Ransom? So you have to pay to get your data back from RAM? :-)) (ok ok sorry :-)) )

Comment: @Axeman - Ah!, Of course! It's a new memory technology for cloud based servers :) - (*I fixed the typo before your comment appeared*)

Comment: @Axeman - Yes, it's for "just in cache" backup. Stores across the network at the speed of write. (On a clear day you can seek forever)(being cloud, day is now substituted for disk).

Answer (score 2):

Terminology: Cache is only called cache because it caches something slower.

- A cache on the CPU uses fast static RAM to cache accesses to slower,
  but cheaper dynamic RAM.
- A disk cache uses dynamic RAM, or flash to
  cache accesses to slower, but cheaper hard disk storage.

I expect what these people are researching is computers with the fast (I suspect static) RAM we normally use for CPU caches as primary storage. It's no longer a cache though.

The computer won't operate any differently except that memory accesses will be high speed all of the time. In current computers you only get that high speed some of the time, when the item is in the cache. Other accesses have to pay the penalty of going to the slower storage.

I'm surprised there's anything to research here. This is how all computers worked before CPUs and DRAM had the huge 10-20x differences in clock speed we have today. Go look at an Apple ][. CPU and memory on the same clock.

To be honest I doubt you'd be able to get 1 or 2GB of the kind of on-chip RAM we use for L1 CPU caches, so I suspect you're still looking at having caches in the system. It's just that what was previously your L2 or L3 Cache is now you primary storage.

Comment: Memory access speed for DRAM is inversely proportional to the log of the size of the memory. The bigger the DRAM, the slower the memory access. Cache is small for the express purpose of speeding this memory access up.

Comment: The corollary for this is if you have 128 gigs of memory, its access speed ends up being similar to that of an SSD.

Comment: @Hans: Did you claim that decoding memory address takes a significant proportion of the time needed to the access time of a memory area? I believe that the access time of 128GB of RAM should be much faster than a 128GB of SSD because the type of memory cell are different because the memory cell in SSD must be persistent while SRAM and DRAM only need to be transient, and also because SSD is read with a much larger block sizes than RAM.